# Mongoose/Nodejs - populate function only returns object id of user

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

Goal: return user information in referenced model.

Issue: I believe my model names (lack of convention) are throwing off the populate function. I'd like to return my users name but am not getting it.

Here's my user model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
profile: {
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String }
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema, 'user');
```

And my item model:

```
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
  },
const PlayLoop = mongoose.model('items', ItemSchema);
```

In my controller, my function looks like this:

```
show(req, res, next) {
    const id = req.params.id
    Items.findById({_id: id})
    .populate({
      path:'User',
    })
    .exec(function(err, item) {
      if (err) {console.log(err)}
      console.log(item)
    })

  },
```

What's returned is my item model:

```
{  _id: ITEM_ID,
  title: 'some title',
  user: USER_ID,
}
```

For the user, I'd like to return the full profile information.
Thoughts?

Comment: `Items.findById({_id: id})
    .populate({
      path:'user',
    })` here `User` should be `user`

Comment: when i update my function to this: `.populate({ path:'user', })` my user returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that the client side code was not pointing to the correct database.